# Share LocationListener with another Activity Android

Tags: java, android, gps, location, listener

I am trying to build an application that needs to use the GPS API's on android. I have two activities that need to use the gps.

The first one is just an activity that has a `LocationListener` and when it gets the location it gets weather for that location from a web API and saves it somewhere.

After doing that, it starts an intent that starts another activity. The other activity on other hand, needs to get speed from gps and update in realtime.

Now my question is, is it possible to use the same `LocationListener` from another activity on the second activity without having to reconnect to gps and do all that stuff again? Or is there any other alternatives than reconnecting again on the second activity as well?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

@KSubedi -- create a class for location listener & use objects of class in both your activity.
 You can create class like below or you can edit below as per you requirement or create new one.

```
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public abstract class MyLocation {
        Timer timer1;
       static LocationManager lm;
        LocationResult locationResult;
        boolean gps_enabled = false;
        boolean network_enabled = false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(MyLocation.lm == null)
            MyLocation.lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try
        {
            gps_enabled = MyLocation.lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}
        try
        {
            network_enabled = MyLocation.lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            MyLocation.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
         if(network_enabled)
             MyLocation.lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
       // timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new GetLastLocation(), 0,50000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            MyLocation.lm.removeUpdates(this);
            MyLocation.lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            MyLocation.lm.removeUpdates(this);
            MyLocation.lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
//             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
//             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc = MyLocation.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc = MyLocation.lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }
    public void closeListeners(){
          timer1.cancel();
      lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
      lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
    public  abstract void locationClick() ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose use [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to get locations instead of using two activites.